# RIP schily (Jörg Schilling)

Tags: discussion

According to [a post on the Unix Heritage Society mailing list](https://minnie.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2021-October/024523.html), prominent FOSS developer and Unix enthusiast, Jörg Schilling passed away on Sunday, 10th October 2021.

He was an [active member of this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/120884/schily) and was generous in sharing his extensive knowledge of Unix and computer systems.

He had strong opinions (loved Solaris, passionate about portability and POSIX, didn’t seem to like GNU or Linux) and wasn’t afraid to express them in a forthright manner.

As the long-time developer of `cdrecord` and `mkisofs`, anyone who has ever copied or burned a CD or DVD on a Unix-like OS has benefited from his work and commitment to quality. Others may also remember his work on developing software for SCSI systems.

Condolences to his loved ones.

Comment: Never mind his bona fide *Greybeard* cred, I will be forever in his debt for `cdrecord` alone. @Schily

Comment: So sad. Will continue to remember the fun time

Comment: I remembered the name but dunno why, when you shared his work on cdrecord and mkisofs I remembered. So many times I was able to make iso's because of him. Although debian now uses genisoimage along with some other tools.

Comment: updated link: https://www.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2021-October/024523.html